# How to retrieve backup of database from app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, ddms

I have trying to copy my app database from storage data to any outher floder 
but i'm getting some error .

my device is rooted and i have used many apps from google play to nevigate to data/data but it's empty and i have used this code :

```
 public void backup() {
        try {
            File sdcard = Environment.getRootDirectory();
            File outputFile = new File(sdcard,
                    "YourDatabase.db");

            if (!outputFile.exists()) 
                 outputFile.createNewFile(); 

            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            File inputFile = new File(data,
                    "data/"+LoginActivity.this.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+"HafilTC.db");
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error(e.toString());
        }
```

android mainfilfist :

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

error log :

```
02-11 18:38:16.213: E/AndroidRuntime(21338): java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Comment: you may try http://stackoverflow.com/a/27463738/730807

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Environment.getRootDirectory()` does not return the root directory of the SD card. It returns the root OS directory, which you cannot write to.

You should instead use [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29), which will return the root directory of the user's external storage directory (which may or may not be an SD Card, depending on the device).

Comment: when using getExternalStorageDirectory(). i get error : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Have you got an SDCard?

Comment: yes i have sd card , but can you give me any other way to save the file on local storage ? without sd card

Comment: What happens when you call [`Environment.getExternalStorageState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState())?

Comment: And is the no such file crash happening with the `sdcard` and `outputFile`, or with the `data` and `inputFile` variables? Either of those pairs could be generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options here.

**Using DDMS**

Open Eclipse, and switch to DDMS perspective.

Than follow the path:

```
DDMS--> file explorer-->data--> data--> your package name-->databases
```

Your database should be inside databases folder, and since you're on a rooted device you can get it.

**Using ADB**

You can use ADB once you have a device connected via USB and with USB debig enabled. To check if your device is correctly connected use:

```
adb devices
```

Than get your DB with these commands (you're copying it to SDCARD, and then reading directly from there):

```
adb -d shell
run-as your.package.name
cat /data/data/your.package.name/databases/database_name.db > /sdcard/your_db_name.db
```

If you want to do it programmatically have a look to what @Tanis.7x suggests.

Comment: option 1: the can't see and folder's but when using emulator i can use this option .

Comment: any chance your /data/data path is somewhere else? Like in system?

Comment: i have searched many times but could not find it , but in ddms there is no any folders

Comment: mmm try the second option, attach the device, open a terminal and give it an 'adb devices'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by remove .db from 
    HafilTC.db

to make it just file name : HafilTC