# How to retrieve the sandbox of my app using Eclipse from my device?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, sandbox, ddms

I have an android app which uses **sharedPreferences**.

I run the app in my android device using Eclipse

I would like to pull the entire **sandbox** from the **device to desktop** so that I can manually see the contents of the sharedPreferences.

I clicked **DDMS** and clicked **FileExplorer** and saw data folder But its empty.

Any help is appreciated !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: your device is rooted ? if its rooted device  then your sharedpreferences  will be inside /data/data/your application package/shared_pref/...

Comment: I thought if we run the app from Eclipse we could pull that using FileExplorer in DDMS

Comment: no..becasue that way you are installing the app in /data/app partition. which we dont have access.  MAX you can read all the sharedpreference entry  programatically .. Let me know if it clears for you.

Comment: Can it be achieved if I run the app in simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If device is rooted may be it's possible.
But in general you can not retrieve the sandbox of your app from your device to pc.

But you can achieve your goal which is getting the sandbox of your app by running your app on **Android Virtual Device(AVD)**.Once the app is installed in AVD.

Switch to **DDMS Perspective** in Eclipse by choosing **Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS**

Below is a sample DDMS screen

[image: DDMS]

In the right side tab choose **File Explorer** then choose **data -> data ->** then see where is you package select it and press **Pull a file from device button** which is the first button on the top left side of image and a dialog box will come like below image choose the folder and the contents of your whole package will be saved

[image: Sandbox]

Now you can open the chosen folder and you can see you apps sandbox contents there

[image]

Comment: Are you sure we can't do this ?

Comment: you can't do this in any non-rooted device as of now and hopefully in future as well.